# Listing values from entities related to the current

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've got a view that shows drivers listing their names and phone numbers. Now, I'd like to add a new column called status. The problem I have is that the status is not a property on a driver.

The status is a property on a job that the driver can be assign to. A single driver can be assigned to a bunch of jobs and I want to list the one with the highest status.

So, let's say that driver and job are defined as follows.

```
[Table("Drivers")]
public class Driver
{
  [Key]
  public int DriverId { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public String Phone { get; set; }
}

[Table("Job")]
public class Job
{
  [Key]
  public int JobId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("Driver")]
  public int DriverId { get; set; }
  public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
  public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

My viewer has this model definition that is sent to the constructor for *View*.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(db.Drivers.ToList());
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
  List<Job> jobs = db.Jobs.Include(o => o.Customer).Include(o => o.Driver);
  ...
  return View(jobs.toList());
}
```

I'm not sure on how to include the information about the job status (at least **any** of them that a driver is assigned to) into the model shown on the index page for drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not add a navigation property to the Driver:

```
[Table("Drivers")]
public class Driver
{
   [Key]
   public int DriverId { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public String Phone { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs {get; set;}
}
```

Your database should already be set up to support this one to many relationship due to the fact that you already have driver referenced on the Job.

then just add:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   db.Include.Drivers(x => x.Jobs);
   return View(db.Drivers.ToList());
}
```

Comment: I used *IEnumerable* instead of *ICollection* and it didn't work. Now that I've switched to your suggestion, it did. Care to explain why *IEnumerable* didn't do the trick?

Comment: IEnumerable is specifically for enumerating through a list, like a query.  you cannot modify the contents of an IEnumerable without turning them into a List or Collection first.  ICollection allows for access to its contents AND the ability to modify them.  Entity Framework wants to allow this ability to modify, so they require an ICollection instead of IEnumerable.